# R Shiny data analysis: I am struggling to render a plot from the .csv file I have uploaded

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, shiny, render

I am building a reliability data analysis tool in R Shiny. I am newish to R (used it once a few years ago) and new to Shiny. I haven't been able to solve this problem via the tutorials or forums :(

Basically, I want the user to upload a .csv file of the failure events table. This table has four columns (i, Xi, Ci and Ti) and can have any number of rows.

First, I want to display the data in table form. This part of my model currently works.

Then, I want to make a plot of Ti vs i. I have written code for it (I've tried many iterations, current code is below), but nothing I have tried works.

Later, I will want to perform statistical operations using the data (starting with a Laplace trend test), which I am also not yet sure how to do (eg. how do I specify which column/row/data item I'm using when performing operations?).

Below is the current R code (I have removed irrelevant sections):

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  #App title
  titlePanel("Reliability Data Analysis Tool"),
  
  tabsetPanel(
    
    tabPanel("Model selection", fluid = TRUE,
             sidebarLayout(
               
               sidebarPanel(
                 
                 "Welcome to the RShiny Reliability Data Analysis tool. 
                 To begin, please upload a valid events table file.", HTML('<br/>'),HTML('<br/>'),
                 
                 
                 #Allow user to input events table in .csv format
                 fileInput(
                   inputId = "fileEventsTable",
                   label = "Upload an events table", 
                   accept = ".csv"),
                 
                 #Indicate whether or not data includes headers   
                 checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                 
                 
               ),
               
               mainPanel(
                 
                 h4("Events table"),
                 
                 h5("Key"),
                 "i = Observation number,",
                 "Xi = Interarrival time,",
                 "Ci = Failure indication,",
                 "Ti = Global time",
                 
                 #Display events table
                 tableOutput("eventsTableContents"),
                 
                 HTML('<br/>'),
                 
                 h4("Cumulative failure plot"),
                 
                 #Display cumulative failure plot 
                 plotOutput("eventsTablePlot")
                 
               )))))
                 
server <- function(input, output) {
                   
                   #Read .csv file as a data frame
                   eventsdataframe<-reactive({
                     if (is.null(input$fileEventsTable))
                       return(NULL)                
                     data<-read.csv2(input$fileEventsTable$datapath)
                   })
                   
                   #Render table from events table data frame
                   output$eventsTableContents <- renderTable({
                     eventsdataframe()
                   })
                   
                   #Render plot from events table data frame
                   output$eventsTablePlot <- renderPlot({
                     ggplot(data = eventsdataframe()  +
                              geom_point(aes(x=eventsdataframe$Ti,y=eventsdataframe$i,size=10)))
                     
                   })
                 }
                 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And this is the current output I get when running it and uploading an appropriate .csv file:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M7D9.png)

Note the error: non-numeric argument to binary operator, where I want the scatter plot to be.

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a issue with reactive dataframe so i have used `observeEvent` for the reactive value and then `isolate` it under the `observeEvent` also instead of using `read.csv2` to read the data i have used `read.csv`  made some little changes and the app is running fine.

You and try this out, i think it serves your purpose.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  #App title
  titlePanel("Reliability Data Analysis Tool"),
  
  tabsetPanel(
    
    tabPanel("Model selection", fluid = TRUE,
             sidebarLayout(
               
               sidebarPanel(
                 
                 "Welcome to the RShiny Reliability Data Analysis tool. 
                 To begin, please upload a valid events table file.", HTML('<br/>'),HTML('<br/>'),
                 
                 
                 #Allow user to input events table in .csv format
                 fileInput(
                   inputId = "fileEventsTable",
                   label = "Upload an events table", 
                   accept = ".csv"),
                 
                 #Indicate whether or not data includes headers   
                 checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)),
               
               mainPanel(
                 
                 h4("Events table"),
                 
                 h5("Key"),
                 "i = Observation number,",
                 "Xi = Interarrival time,",
                 "Ci = Failure indication,",
                 "Ti = Global time",
                 
                 #Display events table
                 tableOutput("eventsTableContents"),
                 
                 HTML('<br/>'),
                 
                 h4("Cumulative failure plot"),
                 
                 #Display cumulative failure plot 
                 plotOutput("eventsTablePlot")
                 
               )))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #Read .csv file as a data frame
  eventsdataframe<-reactive({
    req(input$fileEventsTable)
    data<-read.csv(input$fileEventsTable$datapath)
  })
  
  #df <- eventsdataframe()
  
  #Render table from events table data frame
  output$eventsTableContents <- renderTable({
    eventsdataframe()
  })
  
  #Render plot from events table data frame
  observeEvent(eventsdataframe(), {
    req(eventsdataframe())
    
    ddf <- isolate(eventsdataframe())
    
    output$eventsTablePlot <-renderPlot({
      
      ggplot(data =ddf, aes(x=ddf$Ti,y=ddf$i,size=10))+
        geom_point()
      
      })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And i have tested it with the dummy data [image: App_image]

Comment: Ahh fantastic! Thank you so much! I got it to work using your code but with read.csv2 (it's just got to do with the country I'm in, we use ; as a separator and , as a decimal)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. It looks like an issue with reactive data:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  #App title
  titlePanel("Reliability Data Analysis Tool"),
  
  tabsetPanel(
    
    tabPanel("Model selection", fluid = TRUE,
             sidebarLayout(
               
               sidebarPanel(
                 
                 "Welcome to the RShiny Reliability Data Analysis tool. 
                 To begin, please upload a valid events table file.", HTML('<br/>'),HTML('<br/>'),
                 
                 
                 #Allow user to input events table in .csv format
                 fileInput(
                   inputId = "fileEventsTable",
                   label = "Upload an events table", 
                   accept = ".csv"),
                 
                 #Indicate whether or not data includes headers   
                 checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                 
                 
               ),
               
               mainPanel(
                 
                 h4("Events table"),
                 
                 h5("Key"),
                 "i = Observation number,",
                 "Xi = Interarrival time,",
                 "Ci = Failure indication,",
                 "Ti = Global time",
                 
                 #Display events table
                 tableOutput("eventsTableContents"),
                 
                 HTML('<br/>'),
                 
                 h4("Cumulative failure plot"),
                 
                 #Display cumulative failure plot 
                 plotOutput("eventsTablePlot")
                 
               )))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #Read .csv file as a data frame
  eventsdataframe<-reactive({
    if (is.null(input$fileEventsTable))
      return(NULL)                
    data<-read.csv2(input$fileEventsTable$datapath)
  })
  
  #Render table from events table data frame
  output$eventsTableContents <- renderTable({
    eventsdataframe()
  })
  
  #Render plot from events table data frame
  output$eventsTablePlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = eventsdataframe()  +
             geom_point(aes(x=eventsdataframe()$Ti,y=eventsdataframe()$i,size=10)))
    
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might just be a misplaced `)` in ggplot, and reference the reactive dataframe as `eventsdataframe()` in `geom_point`.

Instead of

```
ggplot(data = eventsdataframe()  +
                              geom_point(aes(x=eventsdataframe$Ti,y=eventsdataframe$i,size=10)))
```

Try this

```
ggplot(data = eventsdataframe())  +
                              geom_point(aes(x=eventsdataframe()$Ti,y=eventsdataframe()$i,size=10))
```

Comment: I tried that now and the error just changes to

error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Sorry, reactive dataframes should be referenced as `eventsdataframe()` in `geom_point` or just use `aes(x=Ti, y=i)`.